# Return the private IP of an EC2 instance from within the EC2 instance

Tags: rhel, amazon-ec2, aws, ip-address, amazon-linux

What specific syntax can be used to return the private IP address of an Amazon Linux EC2 instance from the command line within that instance?

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
# Get private IP from inside the instance by filtering inside the following:
instanceid=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
echo $instanceid
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $instanceid --region us-west-2
```

However, as you can see if you type these commands inside an EC2 instance yourself, the above 3 lines result in a massive output, which would be a mess to filter through manually.

Can someone suggest one or two lines of code to return simply the private ip of the instance and NO other information?

Answer (score 19):

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

> The private IPv4 address of the instance. In cases where multiple network interfaces are present, this refers to the eth0 device (the device for which the device number is 0).
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Alternately:

```
$ ec2metadata --local-ipv4
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed that it will be this particular address,  they are negotiated. Also,  linux professionals disable avahi in VM/enterprise settings.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure what you are saying is negotiated.  It's also unclear why you mention avahi, 
but I assume you are referring to 169.254.169.254.  This is the fixed IP address of the EC2 Metadata service, a service provided by the hypervisor and accessible only from inside the instance.  See also [What's Special about the 169.254.169.254 Address for AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42314029/1695906)